# How to cut a half circle in a plane

Tags: modeling

I have a mirrored object and want to cut out a half oval. But it's a mirror object, so I need a quarter. I was trying with CTRL+SHIFT+B but the result looks not good (upper one/ below, what I want)
Next idear was to create a cylinder and use Bevel Mod but I want a better solution.
And that'ss my question. Does anyone know a good solution to cut out a quarter?
[image]

Comment: the second image is what you want? You want to cut an oval?

Comment: yes, circle was wrong...sorry. I will change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have 'Clamp Overlap' checked in your *Bevel* operator/modifier, you can cut  in  a couple of loops to constrain its extents:

[image]

.. and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> dissolve them away, when they are of no further use.

You could snap the constraining loops to a template ellipse, for accuracy.

Comment: This is what i'd call an elegant blender hack :))

Comment: @JachymMichal`  A  _Hacker_?  ... _Moi_?  How very dare you!  XD..

Answer (score 2):

I would do it another way (I would begin with an oval for example) but if you really want to start with a mirrored plane you can do it with the *Knife Project* tool:

Create the oval object, put it over the plane, switch to top orthographic view, select the plane, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> on the oval, go into the *Mesh panel > Knife Project*. Now your oval shape is cut on the plane:

[image]